# hide specific sub-div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html,

```
<div id="first">
    <div class="block_title">item1</div>
    <div id="first_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="block_title">item2</div>
    <div id="second_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <div class="block_title">item3</div>
    <div id="third_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I want to hide specific sub div from this html.

- In first block, "sub_block_1" will be hidden.
- In second block, "sub_block_2" will be hidden.
- In third block, "sub_block_3" will be hidden.

I tried with this jQuery, but it didn't work. Can you please help me with this problem?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.block_title').each(function(){
var title = jQuery('.block_title').text();

if(title == 'item1'){
    jQuery('.sub_block_1').hide();
}
if(title == 'item2'){
    jQuery('.sub_block_2').hide();
}
if(title == 'item3'){
    jQuery('.sub_block_3').hide();
}
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: `var title = jQuery(this).text();` use this instead of class

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rtz2L9pL/ OR short version https://jsfiddle.net/xd1h2t7j/

Comment: Could you please review my answer and if it is correct please mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `var title = jQuery('.block_title').text();` to `var title = jQuery(this).text();`
and specify the context in which you want to hide sub div.

So following will work

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.block_title').each(function () {
    var title = jQuery(this).text();
    var $parent = jQuery(this).parent();
    if (title == 'item1') {
        jQuery('.sub_block_1', $parent).hide();
    }
    if (title == 'item2') {
        jQuery('.sub_block_2', $parent).hide();
    }
    if (title == 'item3') {
        jQuery('.sub_block_3', $parent).hide();
    }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
    <div class="block_title">item1</div>
    <div id="first_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="block_title">item2</div>
    <div id="second_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <div class="block_title">item3</div>
    <div id="third_block_1">
        <div class="third_block_1">block content 1_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please help me with this? Please see this, https://jsfiddle.net/yqdboLf5/1/

I just wanted to show the "my network" area when tkt_name = "Network Activity" 

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use adjacent sibling selector `+` , `:eq()` with paramter `index` from `.each()`

```js
jQuery(".block_title").each(function(index, el) {
  jQuery("+ > :eq("+ index +")", this).hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
    <div class="block_title">item1</div>
    <div id="first_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="block_title">item2</div>
    <div id="second_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <div class="block_title">item3</div>
    <div id="third_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML:

```
<div id="first">
    <div class="block_title" data-count="1">item1</div>
    <div id="first_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="block_title"  data-count="2">item2</div>
    <div id="second_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <div class="block_title"  data-count="3">item3</div>
    <div id="third_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript part:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.block_title').each(function(){
var countno = jQuery(this).attr("data-count");
var title = jQuery(this).text();
var parent = jQuery(this).parent();
if(title == 'item'+countno){
    jQuery('.sub_block_'+countno,parent).hide();
}
})
});
```

Please refer the [url](https://jsfiddle.net/6unqf9n0/1/)

Comment: thanks buddy for your answer, it's really working. but already selected the best answer for my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.block_title').each(function(){
//var title = jQuery('.block_title').text();
var title =jQuery(this).text();

if(title == 'item1'){
    jQuery('.sub_block_1').hide();

}
if(title == 'item2'){
    jQuery('.sub_block_2').hide();
}
if(title == 'item3'){
    jQuery('.sub_block_3').hide();
}
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
    <div class="block_title">item1</div>
    <div id="first_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_1</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="block_title">item2</div>
    <div id="second_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_2</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <div class="block_title">item3</div>
    <div id="third_block_1">
        <div class="sub_block_1">block content 1_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_2">block content 2_3</div>
        <div class="sub_block_3">block content 3_3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the output that OP desired.